# How to fully navigate a UWP app with just keyboard

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, navigation

I am trying to give my app the ability to work with only keyboard keys. I want it to work under controlled bounds like F9 and F10 control left and right in the navigation bar, F7 and F8 control up and down within the page elements, etc. I know you can tab through every element on the screen by continually hitting Tab but I want to make it more efficient and bounded for the user.

Essentially, I am wondering how I would create a custom navigation scheme with bounds such as mentioned above by only limiting the navigation bounds of a certain key set to just the page tab bar on top, or just scrolling up and down certain elements on the page.

Here is an example of a settings page I am having trouble fully navigating
[image: SettingsPage]

So far I have tried doing this by setting Tab Navigation to "cycle" within certain element bounds and then using certain keyboard keys to trigger code that would simulate a tab or reverse tab press:

```
        void TabLeft()
        {
            InputInjector inputInjector = InputInjector.TryCreate();
            var shift = new InjectedInputKeyboardInfo();
            shift.VirtualKey = (ushort)(VirtualKey.Shift);
            shift.KeyOptions = InjectedInputKeyOptions.None;

            var tab = new InjectedInputKeyboardInfo();
            tab.VirtualKey = (ushort)(VirtualKey.Tab);
            tab.KeyOptions = InjectedInputKeyOptions.None;
            inputInjector.InjectKeyboardInput(new[] { shift, tab });
            shift.KeyOptions = InjectedInputKeyOptions.KeyUp;
            tab.KeyOptions = InjectedInputKeyOptions.KeyUp;
        }

        void TabRight()
        {
            InputInjector inputInjector = InputInjector.TryCreate();
            var info = new InjectedInputKeyboardInfo();
            info.VirtualKey = (ushort)(VirtualKey.Tab);
            inputInjector.InjectKeyboardInput(new[] { info });
        }
```

I have also tried detecting certain key presses, and having the code simulate the click event on one of the buttons on screen. This code works by getting the index of the next button to the left or right, and simulating clicking it.

```
ButtonAutomationPeer peer;
IInvokeProvider invokeProv = null;
ContentPresenter cp = ItemsControlElement.ContainerFromIndex(IndexofNextButton) as ContentPresenter;
peer = new ButtonAutomationPeer(MainPageViewModel.FindVisualChild<Button>(cp));
invokeProv = peer.GetPattern(PatternInterface.Invoke) as IInvokeProvider;
invokeProv.Invoke();
```

Both work to a certain degree but not to the full capacity I need. One issue I have run into is a settings page i have made. I want to be able to navigate to the page with keyboard keys through the page tab bar. Then I was to navigate down the page with other keys, and finally be able to edit the settings textboxes. So far I haven't found an efficient way to control the navigation path as well as the focus manager. Any ideas or help would be much appreciated!

Comment: You could refer [**Keyboard accelerators**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/input/keyboard-accelerators) document.

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT not exactly the objective I was going for, because that is similar to the Keydown event I am already using. But it is actually extremely helpful in letting me keep more code out of the code-behind! So thank you!